# jQuery, how to select immediate next div after several radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with several groups of radio buttons, and several input texts, and after each group, either radios or text, there is a button to save the changes for each group.

what i want to do is, using jQuery, add an handler to the onchange event, so the next button to each group of radios (and texts) gets enabled.

the html is something like this:

```
Antig.<input type="text" name="anosAntiguedad" id="anosAntiguedad" >

<div id='guardan' style="display:<?= $mostrar?>">
    <input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="modifica('anosAntiguedad')" />
</div>

<input type="radio" name="viveCasa" id="viveCasa" value="Propia" >Propia
<input type="radio" name="viveCasa" id="viveCasa" value="Rentada" >Rentada
<input type="radio" name="viveCasa" id="viveCasa" value="Familiares" >Familiares

<div id='guardan' >
    <input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="modifica('viveCasa')" />
</div>
```

I already have the desired behaviour for input texts, and I already activate the corresponding save button on each text's change with jQuery. like this:

```
$('input:text')
        .bind('change ',function(){ 
            $(this).next("div").children(":button")
                .attr("disabled",false);        
    });
```

But if i do something similar using an initial $(":radio") selector, it doesn't work as expected, becasue it only activates the save button if the LAST radio in the group is changed (since i use .next ) . Also, if instead of .next I use .siblings, i get ALL the divs with buttons in the page since all of them have the same parent as the inputs (radios and text). I want to get the button's div after every radios group, not just after the last radio.

For more clarity, please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64mqU/)

Notes:

- I am using jQuery 1.3, so thats why i use attr() instead of prop() yo
  change the disabled property.
- I CANNOT change the html code, only the jQuery code, so changing
  anything in the html is not viable. Plus, there are even more radio groups, amog with other text inputs (each with a save button)
- I KNOW that it is an error that every div has the same "guardan" id,
  but again, that is the way the code is and i cannot change it.

Wrapping up. I need a way to enable the corresponding save button to each radio button groups when the radios get changed. The save buttons are always wrapped inside divs, and the divs are always after either the radio or the text inputs. I need it to work in jQuery, preferably 1.3, but i COULD change it to a newer version if necesary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) , with a `div:first` filter, like this:

```
   $('input:radio')
        .bind('change ',function(){ 
            $(this).nextAll("div:first").children(":button")
                .attr("disabled",false);        
    });
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/64mqU/1/)

Comment: o_O! so simple (and fast) answer I'm impressed! thanks! I wasn't even aware of the .nextAll() function, and forgot about :first pseudo-class . Thanks again!

Comment: I was forced to wait some minutes before accepting it, but there you go!

Comment: +1, Some addition to selector `$('input:text, input:radio').bind('change ',function(){ 
    $(this).nextAll("div:first").children(":button").attr("disabled",false);   
});`

Comment: Yes, as Sheikh Heera says, you can reuse the above code for the input texts too, just select both radio and input texts as `$('input:text, input:radio')`. Thanks Sheikh! :-)

Comment: nice! I thought of doing that to, but since I also need to check for keypress on :text (not mentioned or show in the example, since it was only a portion of the whole thing) and i also need to add MORE input types (selects an textareas) with other conditions/events for their matching buttons, i kept them separate. But definitely worth mentioning, It puts me in the right direction for further validations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be optimized, but:

```
$(":radio").change(function(){
    var nextButton = function($but) { 
        if ($but.next().is('DIV')) {
            $but.next().find(":button").attr("disabled",false);
        } else {
            nextButton($but.next());
        }

    }
    nextButton($(this));
});
```